# TriggerHandler not taking parameters

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have an event handler bound to a div using mousedown. When I click on some other div, I'm triggering this handler as well.

```
//The original binding
$('#somediv').on('mousedown', { key: 'value' }, handlers.downHandler);

//This is what I'm doing to trigger the above handler
$('#someotherdiv').on('mousedown', function(e){
    $(#somediv').triggerHandler('mousedown', { secondkey: 'secondvalue' });
});
```

The `downHandler` looks like this:

```
function downHandler(e){
    console.log(e.data.key); //Prints value

    if(typeof e.data.secondkey !== 'undefined')
        console.log(e.data.secondkey)
    else
        console.log('Undefined');
}
```

Now, in my handler, `e.data` has only the key value from the original binding, and not second key/second value from the trigger. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: what is the value of `secondvalue` in `$(#somediv').triggerHandler('mousedown', { secondkey: 'secondvalue' });`? where are you getting the value?

Comment: I'm just testing it with sample keys/values. I'm not getting any data that I send from the trigger, but the data I send from the original call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extrcparameter argument is passes as additional parameter to the event handler, not as the data object

Try

```
//The original binding
$('#somediv').on('mousedown', {
    key: 'value'
}, function (e, extra1) {
    console.log('data', e.data)
    console.log('extra1', extra1)
});

//This is what I'm doing to trigger the above handler
$('#someotherdiv').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    $('#somediv').triggerHandler('mousedown', {
        secondkey: 'secondvalue'
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FyLF9/)

Comment: I'm waiting for the time limit to finish so that I can accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$('#somediv').triggerHandler('mousedown', { 'secondkey': secondvalue});
```

Comment: I don't think that's needed!